# How to add a type to the typesUseViewActionInListings with Generic Setup?

Tags: plone, genericsetup

How to add a type "MyType" to the `typesUseViewActionInListings` property of the `site_properties` property in the `portal_properties` tool?

Using a propertiestool.xml file with GenericSetup as the following will modify the existing/default types (Image, File) to only (MyType). I need instead add MyType to the existing.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_properties" meta_type="Plone Properties Tool">
  <object name="site_properties" meta_type="Plone Property Sheet">
    <property name="typesUseViewActionInListings" type="lines">
      <element value="MyType"/>
    </property>
  </object>
</object>
```

One could think adding all types (existing and new). This is won't suffice for us since we do not want to assume which types are already in `typesUseViewActionInListings`

```xml
  <element value="File"/>
  <element value="Image"/>
  <element value="MyType"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`purge="False"` does the trick!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_properties" meta_type="Plone Properties Tool">
  <object name="site_properties" meta_type="Plone Property Sheet">
    <property name="typesUseViewActionInListings" type="lines" purge="False">
      <element value="MyType"/>
    </property>
  </object>
</object>
```

Comment: @wolfrevo: The [GenericSetup Best Practices](http://developer.plone.org/components/genericsetup.html#best-practices) in the Plone dev docs look like a good starting place.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Thanks for the hint. What I'm really searching for is a documentation (maybe source code) where those attributes are (at least) listed. Some attributes and the corresponding values are more or less obvious (like name, meta_type, type, value etc.). But other attributes are not obvious.
For instance, I would like to know whether there is something like 'remove="True"'. The question an the answer above show how to add a type. But what about removing a type (if existing)?

Comment: Add `'remove="True"'` to the `<element ... 'remove="True"' />`.